# Is it possible to listen to Cortana's states?

Tags: windows, cortana

I'm working on a desktop application that focuses on listening to Cortana states, but I don't want to intercept a specific question and treat that response.

I want to be able to know exactly when I say "Hey cortana!" and it starts listening, and then I want to know exactly when it stops listening and processes an answer.

Is that possible? Does anyone have an idea on how it could be achieved?

Comment: Perhaps this might be what you are looking for? https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand

Comment: Not really, I believe.
I want to get a callback of when cortana is actually listening to me. When I say "hey cortana" i want to receive a callback saying it activated listening mode, for example.

Comment: "desktop application" are you talking about a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) App or a bit 32 Program?

Comment: A UWP, though I'm not worrying about other platforms.
I actually got support from Microsoft and they say it is not possible for third-party applications to get the Cortana state. So I guess this question is closed for now